# GLSL output corrupted when using layout image2D

Tags: glsl

I am having a problem with corrupted OpenGL displays.  If I knew what caused it I could giver a better description, but here goes...

I have a GLSL shader as follows that draws a square and then does a basic box blur over it.  This is the smallest example code I could make to show the problem.

```
#version 430

uniform float time;
uniform int frames;
uniform vec2 resolution;

const int image_width=960;
const int image_height=540;

layout (binding=1,r32f) uniform image2D layer1;

int x_pixel,y_pixel,xp,yp,x_res,y_res,range,range_div;
float layer1_result;

//rectangular neighborhood blur
float Rectangular_Neighborhood(int range) {
    float f=0.0;
    int range_div=(range*2+1)*(range*2+1);
    for (int y=y_pixel-range;y<=y_pixel+range;y++) {
        for (int x=x_pixel-range;x<=x_pixel+range;x++) {
            int xp=x;
            int yp=y;
            if (xp<0) { xp=xp+x_res; }
            if (xp>=x_res) { xp=xp-x_res; }
            if (yp<0) { yp=yp+y_res; }
            if (yp>=y_res) { yp=yp-y_res; }
            f+=imageLoad( layer1, ivec2(xp,yp) ).r;
        }
    }
    f=f/range_div;
    return f;
}

void main()
{
    x_pixel=int(gl_FragCoord.x);
    y_pixel=int(gl_FragCoord.y);
    x_res=int(resolution.x);
    y_res=int(resolution.y);
    
    //initially draw the white square pixels
    if(time<1.0) {
        vec4 col;
        if ((abs(x_res/2-x_pixel)<100)&&(abs(y_res/2-y_pixel)<100)) { col=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0); } else { col=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); }
         imageStore( layer1, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), vec4(col.r,0,0,1));
        gl_FragColor=col;
    } else {
        float f,r,g,b;
        //blur the pixels
        f=Rectangular_Neighborhood(3);
        
        //PROBLEM LINE
        //f=f+0.05; if (f>1.0) { f=f-1.0; } if (f<0.0) { f=f+1.0; }
        
        layer1_result=f;
    
        //SQUARE RENDERS FINE
        //layer1_result=imageLoad( layer1, ivec2(x_pixel,y_pixel) ).r;
        
        imageStore( layer1, ivec2(x_pixel,y_pixel), vec4(layer1_result,0,0,1));

        //display RGB values based on layer values
        r=layer1_result;
        g=layer1_result;
        b=layer1_result;
        
        //update display
        gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
    }
    
}
```

When run, it generates a square for the first 2 seconds and then begins to blur it with a basic box blur.  This works as expected and gives an image like the following

https://ibb.co/y4C4pnT

The problem comes when I uncomment the line after //PROBLEM LINE that adds a small amount to the blur value.  This should just bump all values up, but it corrupts the image/array somehow.  Gives the following result

https://ibb.co/zJFtPyV

Just in case this is how I declare the layer1 image

```
  glGenTextures(1,@layer1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,layer1);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, imwidth, imheight, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, nil);
  glBindImageTexture( 1,                  //unit
                      layer1,             //texture
                      0,                  //level
                      false,              //layered
                      0,                  //layer
                      GL_READ_WRITE,      //access
                      GL_R32F);           //format
```

I think what should happen is that while blurring the square and background should get evenly brighter until the pixels that pass pure white then get wrapped back to 0.  But it should not have these almost random like patterns and that diagonal line?

I thought it may have been how I am passing the image data to and from the shader, but if I uncomment the line after //SQUARE RENDERS FINE then I get the square repeatedly rendering as expected without any corruption.

Any ideas what I may be missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: I see an awful lot of loading from and storing to the same image within the same shader invocation. And an awful lot of those loads are coming from fragment locations *other than* the current location.

Comment: Is that a problem?  To do a blur I need to read the values of neighboring pixels to the current location/pixel.  If it was an issue then wouldn't the correct working image also be corrupted?

Comment: "*Is that a problem?*" Are you asking if it's a problem for different instances of a shader to read and modify the same memory without synchronization? ***[Yes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access)*** "*If it was an issue then wouldn't the correct working image also be corrupted?*" Undefined behavior is undefined. Sometimes, things can "work", but that doesn't mean your code is well-behaved.

Comment: I tried to add glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS); before the call to the quad that renders the shader, but it didn't help.  Howe do I ensure the memory is synchronized?  My end goal here is to be able to pass multiple Image2D that I use as a 2D array of float values.  Those arrays are modified (with more complex code than this basic blur operation) repeatedly.  What if I had separate Image2Ds for input and output, would that help?  Then I would be only reading the input values (from any location) but writing only to the current pixel location.

Comment: "*I tried to add glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS); before the call to the quad that renders the shader, but it didn't help.*" Nor would it be expected to. You cannot do what you're doing this way. You have to read from an image you're *not* also writing to.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using 2 textures and using a switch statement to swap between them each frame.  That means only one texture is being read (at different memory locations) while the other is being written to (only at the current pixel location).  Thanks for the pointer about why my original code would never work.